# yeoman - Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yo

When I run any form of: `yo` or `yo --version` I always get this
(the node and yo and any generator installation worked without errors)

> C:\Users\Leandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\grouped-queue\lib\queue.js:1
>   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { w�$����p�I&�W�0KΔ
>                                                                  ^
>   SyntaxError: **Invalid or unexpected token**
>       at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:545:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:500:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object.  (C:\Users\Leandro\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\node_modules\yeoman-environment\lib\environment.js:8:20)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)

Comment: What version of `node` are you running?